# Spark Structured Streaming: Importing image files to create a simple ML app

Tags: scala, image-processing, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to build a Structured Streaming application which purpose is to retrieve images from an URL and build a pretty simple ML model that would do a classification based on the content of the image.

I have an URL (http://129.102.240.235/extraits/webcam/webcam.jpg) which is updated every X unit of time with a new image. My goal would be first to store those images or to import them directly using a readStream object (if it possible?). I know that since Spark 2.X we can directly use an `image` format to read content into a Dataframe. I was hesitating between different approach:

- using a message's bus solution (as Kafka) that will produce my content to be consumed in Spark, I thought that this would not be bad because Kafka can be used to replicate files so the data loss is weaker.
- Directly make use of the readStream object to read the image (This is what I tried to do, see below)

My next Scala code's purpose is just trying to show the content of the image , but it throws different errors when I test it using `spark-shell`, I will comment the errors on the corresponding part of my below code.

```
scala> val url = "http://129.102.240.235/extraits/webcam/webcam.jpg"
url: String = http://129.102.240.235/extraits/webcam/webcam.jpg

scala> spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)

scala> val image_df = spark.read.format("image").load("file://"+SparkFiles.get("webcam.jpg"))
image_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [image: struct<origin: string, height: int ... 4 more fields>]

scala> image_df.select("image.origin").show(false)
19/10/25 13:33:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: File /tmp/spark-28741963-fd2d-44c2-8a6b-a489fdaae96d/userFiles-95b99fde-a1e2-4da6-9a17-382bfd2292c4/webcam.jpg exists and does not ma
tch contents of http://129.102.240.235/extraits/webcam/webcam.jpg
```

I also tried with using readStream:

```
scala> val scheme = " origin STRING, height INT, width INT, nChannels INT, mode INT, data BINARY"
scheme: String = " origin STRING, height INT, width INT, nChannels INT, mode INT, data BINARY"

scala> val image_df = spark.readStream.format("image").schema(scheme).load("file://"+SparkFiles.get("webcam.jpg"))
image_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [origin: string, height: int ... 4 more fields]

scala> val query_show = image_df.collect.foreach(println).writeStream.format("console").start()
<console>:26: error: value writeStream is not a member of Unit
       val query_show = image_df.collect.foreach(println).writeStream.format("console").start()

// Based on what I red on StackO question, I suppose that this error might be caused because 
// .writeStream should be on the next line, so I tried to put it on 2 lines but..

scala> val query_show = image_df.collect.foreach(println).
     |   writeStream.format("console").start()
<console>:27: error: value writeStream is not a member of Unit
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value writeStream'?
         writeStream.format("console").start()

// Also tried without declaring query_show but returns the same error..
// I know that if I make it work I will have to add query_show.awaitTermination()
```

Any help on debugging this code or idea to build my streaming pipeline would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a way to `show()` my dataframe red using the "image" format. 
I did it in 2 steps:
1/ run a Python script that would save the jpg image from the URL, the script is:

```py
import urllib.request
import shutil


filename = '~/dididi/bpi-spark/images'
url = "http://129.102.240.235/extraits/webcam/webcam.jpg"

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(filename, 'ab') as out_file:  
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

2/ Then, using spark-shell I just executed those 2 lines:

```scala
val image_df = spark.read.format("image").option("inferSchema", true).load("bpi-spark/images").select($"image.origin",$"image.height",$"image.width", $"image.mode", $"image.data")

scala> image_df.show()
+--------------------+------+-----+----+--------------------+
|              origin|height|width|mode|                data|
+--------------------+------+-----+----+--------------------+
|file:///home/niki...|   480|  720|  16|[3C 3D 39 3C 3D 3...|
+--------------------+------+-----+----+--------------------+
```